# Vue.js + axios = data not updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue.js and I try to solve an issue that seems too strange *( at least to me )*.

I have the following code:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import axios from 'axios';

import './components/top-line';

new Vue(
  {
    el      : '#weatherWidget',
    data : {
      loading : false,
      error: '',
      current : null,
      daily   : null,
    },
    created : () => {
      let self = this;
      let form_data = new FormData();
      form_data.append( 'action', 'weather_request' );
      form_data.append( 's', window.vue_weather.s );

      self.loading = true;
      self.error = '';

      axios
        .post( window.vue_weather.ajax_url, form_data )
        .then(
          response => {
            let data = response.data;
            self.current = data.data.currently;
            self.daily   = data.data.daily.data;
            self.loading = false;

            console.log( self );
          }
        )
        .catch(
          error => {
            this.error = error;
          }
        );
    },
  }
);
```

And when the `created` method is executed, I can see in the console the following output:

[image: The output of the self]

But the Vue console seems like that:

[image: The Vue console]

Thus, while the `created` is executed normally, the `Vue` `data` is not updated.

Do you think I am doing anything wrong? Unfortunately, I cannot see something wrong.

Any solution or idea in order to solve the issue?

**NOTES**

- The AJAX Request returns data
- I have also tried the `this` instead of the `let self = this;`

Comment: don't use arrow function for created hook. use `created() {` or `created : function() {` . See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: @JacobGoh thank you for your reply. Finally, that solved the issue. But why happened that? If you like, could you make an answer? I can upvote your answer, as this solved my issue. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using arrow function in the `created` hook.

You can find the reason in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks,

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as
> `created: () = console.log(this.a)` or `vm.$watch('a', newValue => this.myMethod())`. Since arrow functions are bound to the parent
> context, `this` will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect, often
> resulting in errors such as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined` or `Uncaught TypeError: this.myMethod is not a function`.

you can either use

```
created() {
```

or

```
created : function() {
```

Comment: Wow, good catch Jacob, so easy to miss that one. This was an interesting question and same is your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @JacobGoh. You solved my issue !! :) You are the best ;)